# Infer generic type of class based on the type of a object constructor argument's property

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How can I make TS infer the generic type of a class based on the property of a constructor's object argument?
I tried

```js
interface ExampleOptions {
  type: ExampleType,
  ...
}

type ExampleType = ...;

export class Example<T extends ExampleType> {
  public constructor(options: ExampleOptions & {
    type: T,
  }) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do?  Could you provide a [mre] that  clearly demonstrates the difference between success and failure when we copy and paste it into our own  IDEs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by making class generic extend `ExampleOptions` instead:

```
interface ExampleOptions {
  type: ExampleType,
  ...
}

type ExampleType = ...;

export class Example<T extends ExampleOptions> {
  private readonly _type: T['type'];

  public constructor(options: T) {
    this._type = options.type;
  }
}
```